# how to create a blur effect for menu on ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mobile

I have an app. What I want to do is when I tap on a button or a bar button item or a row of a table, then a menu with two items will appear and users can click on it to select an item that they want to choose and the background behind that menu will be blur until an item is chosen. I try to search a control on [cocoacontrols.com](http://cocoacontrols.com) to handle that business but can't find anything. Any suggestions to do this feature?

Comment: Have you tried [UIVisualEffectView](https://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial)?

Answer (score 0):

D

Try this

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect   effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

[self.view addSubview:blurEffectView];
```

This will create a nice blur effect as same as the native iPhone blur effect